# How do I prove that this function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous at the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

My textbook gives the function

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\
0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)
\end{cases}
$$

as an example of a function that isn't continuous at the origin, but I'm having trouble seeing why this is the case.

The book suggests using the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of continuity, which says for $f$ to be continuous at $(0, 0)$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that if $\left\lVert (x, y)\right\rVert < \delta$, then $|f(x, y)| < \epsilon$.

Here's what I tried. I know that from the Euclidean norm definition, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta$, which through some algebra, tells me that $x^2 < \delta^2 \implies |x| < |\delta|$, and the same holds true for $y$.

So
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}\right\rvert
&< \left\lvert \frac{\delta^3}{x^4 + y^2}\right\rvert
\end{align}

but if I want that expression to be less than some $\epsilon$, I'm not sure how to manipulate it to see that. Is there another way to this using the $\epsilon, \delta$ method, or am I forgetting something simple from calculus?

Comment: take the limit approaching (0,0) along the line $y=x$ , it doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do something easier than the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.  For $f$ to be continuous at $(0,0)$, we need that $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = f(0,0) = 0 $.  So for any path we take toward $(0,0)$, we need that the function values of that path also need to go to $0$.

Well, what about the path $(x,y) = (x, x^{2})$?  If $x \neq 0$, but $x \to 0$, then $(x, x^{2}) \to (0,0)$, right?  But $f(x,x^{2}) = \dfrac{x^{4}}{x^{4} + x^{4}} =\dfrac{1}{2}$ for all $x \neq 0$, which means the limit as $x \to 0$ of $f(x,y)$ is equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$, right?  But as $x \to 0$, the path $(x, x^{2})$ goes to $(0,0)$, and we just saw along this path, $f(x,y)$ goes to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

But for $f$ to be continuous at $(0,0)$, we would need $f(x,y)$ to go to $0$ for *every* path going to $(0,0)$, and we just found a path where this doesn't happen.  So $f$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ah, yes. That strategy does seem similar from calculus, now that you laid it out in detail. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael You're welcome!

Comment: To satisfy my own curiosity, do you know of a reference I could look out that discusses the relationship (if any) between continuity in terms of paths and continuity in terms of $\epsilon, \delta$? I'm working my way through a few analysis books on my own, so this isn't homework, but I'm curious how your answer would be formulated in terms of $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs.

Comment: @Michael I think this video is pretty good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCDxj3g_BVk

Comment: @Michael The function they use is similar to (but not exactly the same as) yours.